# Grails: pre-set fileUpload with CommonsMultipartFile from session

Tags: session, grails, file-upload

I want to serve the user with a file that was previously selected when she re-enters the file upload page. My approach is, to keep the file as a CommonsMultipartFile in the Grails 2.5.6 session under `session.lastUpdate.file` and reload it from there. I've already rendered the file name in the textbox that I use for the file dialog. But when submitting, I am told that there is no file selected. Current code is following (excerpt):

```
<!-- _uploadFile.gsp -->
<g:uploadForm action="uploadFile">  
<ul class="list-group content-list">
    <li class="list-group-item">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">Datei</span>
            <g:if test="session.lastUpdate?.file">
                <span class="form-control" id="uploadFileLabel">${session.lastUpdate?.file.originalFilename}</span>
            </g:if>
            <g:else>
                <span class="form-control" id="uploadFileLabel">No file selected</span>
            </g:else>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul class="list-group content-list">
    <li class="list-group-item">
        <label class="btn btn-link btn-file">
            <input type="file" name="uploadFile" style="display: none;"/>Choose a file
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Choose a file" class="btn btn-success" />
        <script>
            jQuery(document).on('change', ':file', function() {
                var input = $(this),
                    numFiles = input.get(0).files ? input.get(0).files.length : 1,
                    label = input.val().replace(/\\/g, '/').replace(/.*\//, '');
                    jQuery('#uploadFileLabel').text(label);
            });
        </script>
    </li>
</ul>
</g:uploadForm>
```

Comment: HTML and JavaScript do not allow you to pre-populate file inputs, as this would be a huge security hole.   You could just pick file paths that may or may not exist and upload them when the user clicked submit.

Comment: Thanks, @billjamesdev! That makes sense. So I'm going to handle it on the controller side.